# JSPlumb Community -- Drag from one container to another container

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jsplumb

I'm trying to make something like this https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/demos/toolkit/flowchart-builder/index.html on the community edition. It doesn't need to be as fully-featured, but I'd like the 'grab an element from the left, drop it on the right' functionality.

I can see from the community documentation that I can build most of what is on the right side of that view.

The question is, how do I create elements that can be dragged from a palette on the left side to the container on the right? Their documentation mentions making elements draggable, but how do I make an element draggable from one container, then when it lands in another container it draws a different element at the same position?

Comment: Did you ever work this out? I'm trying to do the exact same thing, but can't find a single bit of advice anywhere.

Comment: Nope. I could never find any documentation either. Ended up switching to mxGraph